# hide checked radio input value in url (get method)

Tags: javascript, html

If my url looks like this after submitting a form with GET method

```
website.com/page.html?radioVar=1&hiddenVar=12
```

- the radioVar is the value of a checked radio button input
- the hiddenVar is the value of a hidden input

is there any way to "hide" the `radioVar=1` AND keep the `hiddenVar=12` ?

so basically to only have the URL look like `website.com/page.html?hiddenVar=2` knowing that the hiddenVar is an array of radioVar and another variable.

Comment: You will most likely want to use a POST method if you don't want a value displayed in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you Should do the submit manually by javascript or jQuery. And you should use POST method. I'll do it by jQuery.

Set an id for submit button in html like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit">
```

or

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

then in script tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnSubmit').on('click',function(e){
            //cancel the submit button default event first
            e.preventDefault();

            //Then prepare your form data manually
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("hiddenVar", $('#hidden-element-id').val());

            //Then Submit formData by jQuery Post Method
            $.post('proper/url', formData, function(result){
                alert(result);
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to hide a variable  passed in URL you can use the History API, but it does require a modern browser.
Add the following code in your js file:

```
 history.replaceState({}, null, "/page.html?hiddenVar=2");
```

So your URL will appear as website.com/page.html?hiddenVar=2  without reloading the page.

More information here:

[History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: thanks, if I could mark 2 answers as solved I would definitely mark yours too, unfortunately I can't upvote either, I'll remember to upvote your answer when I get enough reputation, thank you for your time !